# Light-colored icon on ActionBar not visible on system menu?

Tags: android

I am using the ActionBarCompat sample. If our action bar has a dark background, we want to use white-colored icons. But these icons are also used for the system menu items (when they don't fit on the action bar, pre-honeycomb). So the white icons aren't visible on the system menu white background. Example:

[image: action bar icon on titlebar and system menu]

What can we do about this? Is there a way to use the dark version of icons when shown on the system menu, and light colored when on the action bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to handle this issue. Either change the color of your ActionBar, or edit the color of your icons.

I would suggest that best combination for Actionbar and icons would be Red color for Actionbar and white color for your icons.

And how can white icons be visible in white background???

If you remember in Menu icons we have grey background with white icons. That's why they are easily visible in Menu's.

Comment: Hi, yes I know what you're saying, but I'm asking more if there's an easy way to switch icons depending if they're ending up on the action bar vs the system menu. Changing the color of my action bar isn't going to work for apps that already have had a particular branding in place for some time.